# Proper .htaccess Method to Redirect a Few Select Pages to use HTTPS, Returning all Others to HTTP?

Tags: .htaccess, joomla-sef-urls

I've looked through similar questions but not found the exact working solution I'm after.

We have a Joomla site that needs 2-3 specific pages to be forced to use https, while navigating away from these pages needs to return to http for all other pages. All pages 'can' come up with either http or https, but https causes some issues with a few plugins.

We have already setup a few things on the .htaccess file, but I don't know all the syntax to do what I'm after. We have mod_rewrite on, a rule that redirects http:// to http://www., and the default Joomla rules that do the SEF urls.

So our secure pages are usually: /section/category/secure-page, /othersection/othercategory/secure-page 2, etc.

---

**HERE'S OUR ENTIRE HTACCESS AFTER IMPLEMENTING THE FIX (BUT GETTING ERROR):**

```
##
# @version $Id: htaccess.txt 10492 2008-07-02 06:38:28Z ircmaxell $
# @package Joomla
# @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2008 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
# Joomla! is Free Software
##

#####################################################
#  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
#
#####################################################

##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits


########## Begin - SSL Redirects (https/http)
#
RewriteRule %{HTTPS}  off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/news-events/cultivate-la/cultivate-la-tickets$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/news-events/cultivate-la/cla-tickets-thankyou$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/news-events/cultivate-la/cla-tickets-decline$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/news-events/cultivate-la/cla-tickets-error$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/how-to-help/donate/make-a-donation/$
RewriteRule (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1  [L]

RewriteRule %{HTTPS}  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/news-events/cultivate-la/cultivate-la-tickets$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/news-events/cultivate-la/cla-tickets-thankyou$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/news-events/cultivate-la/cla-tickets-decline$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/news-events/cultivate-la/cla-tickets-error$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/how-to-help/donate/make-a-donation/$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1  [L]
#
##########


########## Begin - Redirect http:// to http://www. AND /annual subdirectory to annual. subdomain
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.org/$1 [L,R=301]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/annual/(.*)$ http://annual.domainname.org/$1
#
##########

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /


########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section



########## Begin - 301 Redirect short URL
#
Redirect 301 /clatickets https://www.domainname.org/news-events/cultivate-la/cultivate-la-tickets
```

Comment: Anyone else have any guesses why this might not be working properly? The client is getting pretty stressed and I'm not sure where else to look. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, our developer found a plugin for Joomla that forces certain pages to use HTTPS and all other to use HTTP. It has some other handy features as well. Not sure exactly what's going on behind the scenes, but it works great (where the .htaccess methods weren't) so we won't complain.

The plugin is called: Yireo SSL Redirection.

It can be found here: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/url-redirection/11326

Answer (score 0):

note: I deleted my previous answer. it's my new answer:

```
##
# @version $Id: htaccess.txt 10492 2008-07-02 06:38:28Z ircmaxell $
# @package Joomla
# @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2008 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
# Joomla! is Free Software
##

#####################################################
#  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
#
#####################################################

##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits


########## Begin - SSL Redirects (https/http)
#
RewriteRule %{HTTPS}  off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/news-events/cultivate-la/cultivate-la-tickets$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/news-events/cultivate-la/cla-tickets-thankyou$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/news-events/cultivate-la/cla-tickets-decline$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/news-events/cultivate-la/cla-tickets-error$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/how-to-help/donate/make-a-donation/$
RewriteRule (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1  [L]

RewriteRule %{HTTPS}  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/news-events/cultivate-la/cultivate-la-tickets$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/news-events/cultivate-la/cla-tickets-thankyou$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/news-events/cultivate-la/cla-tickets-decline$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/news-events/cultivate-la/cla-tickets-error$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/how-to-help/donate/make-a-donation/$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1  [L]
#
##########


########## Begin - Redirect http:// to http://www. AND /annual subdirectory to annual. subdomain
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.org/$1 [L,R=301]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/annual/(.*)$ http://annual.domainname.org/$1
#
##########

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /


########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section



########## Begin - 301 Redirect short URL
#
Redirect 301 /clatickets https://www.domainname.org/news-events/cultivate-la/cultivate-la-tickets
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply.  I tried using your example to create my rules. I duplicated the second RewriteCond of each section for each additional page to be redirected/ignored (there are 5 pages total that need https).  
  
But the secure pages now don't come up and I get this error:  
The page isn't redirecting properly – Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.  
  
I would paste my code in here, but can't figure out how to do it with the comment limits and mini-Markdown (which really doesn't work right).
  
Ideas??

Comment: @Kenny Please update your question with your current FULL htaccess. The error message suggests that you did something wrong and it keeps redirecting over and over again.

Comment: @Kenny Please update your question with your current FULL htaccess.

Comment: Done. Let me know if I'm following proper protocol for posting here. I didn't find a lot of instruction in the FAQ. THANKS!

Comment: Thank you! Tried that, but it shut the whole site down (got same error for all pages). I'm assuming you just changed the additional part added for https/http, correct? Does it have anything to do with any of the other redirects happening (like http:// to http://www) and/or the order of them?

Comment: @Kenny perhapps putting that part in above of all other rewrite rules solve the problem!

Comment: OK, I tried putting the block of code at the top of the document, but still caused the whole site to not function. I then put it at the bottom of the document (after the Joomla SEF stuff), and this no longer causes the site to crash, but it just doesn't do anything (doesn't force https or vice-versa). Any other ideas???